# Can't connect to mariadb outside of docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

i'm trying to establish connection to mariadb database running on docker container. It is starting using docker compose:

```
  local_maria_db:
    image: mariadb:10.1
    ports:
      - "6603:5432"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "testdb"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    volumes:
      - ${MARIA_CNF_PATH}:/etc/mysql/conf.d/
    networks:
      - vpc1
    restart: always
```

Here is my .cnf file:

`bind-address = 0.0.0.0`

When i'm trying to access that DB outside of docker container using `mysql`:

`mysql --user=root --password=password --port=6603 --host=localhost testdb`

I'm getting

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

When im trying to establish connection using `Sequelize` running on different container but in the same network with this data:

```
 maria_db_connection: {
    database: "testdb",
    dialect: "mariadb",
    username: "root",
    password: "password",
    host: "local_maria_db",
    port: 5432
  }
```

Im getting `ECONNREFUSED`

When I execute `mysql` command inside docker container

```
mysql --user=root --password=password testdb
```

It connects with no problem

```
MariaDB [testdb]>
```

EDIT:

Docker container inspect:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "0a841717401c08b7153d88010d55ce204a9fda4f6cb679819a7d0da818d1e25a",
        "Created": "2021-03-21T17:40:43.015346154Z",
        "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "mysqld"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 26023,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2021-03-21T17:49:19.57736344Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2021-03-21T17:49:11.732752669Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:4a2fed152fe12cbc1e1adbebcc89035df6f230b7c0c0c955c90827826e3bdf59",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/0a841717401c08b7153d88010d55ce204a9fda4f6cb679819a7d0da818d1e25a/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/0a841717401c08b7153d88010d55ce204a9fda4f6cb679819a7d0da818d1e25a/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/0a841717401c08b7153d88010d55ce204a9fda4f6cb679819a7d0da818d1e25a/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/0a841717401c08b7153d88010d55ce204a9fda4f6cb679819a7d0da818d1e25a/0a841717401c08b7153d88010d55ce204a9fda4f6cb679819a7d0da818d1e25a-json.log",
        "Name": "/pccr_local_maria_db_1",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/Users/krystiank/db/maria_cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d:rw"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "pccr_vpc1",
            "PortBindings": {
                "5432/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "6603"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "always",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d6da8b7be1c593baffb442523f3ffd6fb96a9a2036d8bdac5996a5897c6efd90-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/85a09a45a7059dff07262e9a3d89b65303a75b514a789335fe3d84fa81e23a5c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/33fc523d3c873464f8a5a394dfe0ece4990a2b68d2dddfbcb1f7ae86e87e0cb6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/503b045a316c1977d0d0fae6d336094b56fa591682d812d52a5371cc450b9596/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5fe0709b633a59d99c60d4f122fcc3aaaed2913e3d6718dd90d4568173e75b11/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bb60c3716445387fd4c526f72bd2b93c263babbce38f6bb1276985c34d28aa6f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/602c47432472dae0a7eef2dcf91f270090ed9c8ff2d6e0e5688b6f1792895c11/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/24e5c83a0e9ac4f4fe38c9ba349db2cee1c79327da8a663e230bad3a22eea957/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/35307c36b0e275d1dcd6e671e6092a5313af6cdbd60a7671de1dc1346d7f6cb0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4639a60f3e8609d8da66e0d8cbb8b4f5a5f00c697a8b2adba4f11325e34ac21b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6c01eeaf5c7c886f684f052b9528d8495322768502c916959ddf585998c3b92c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9f41f16ff822550d90ad62513def9f0cfe5229e37bb34b909a72f1a683d6fb07/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ea2fc40c561756f7d9ce97f2741ddadded740f81a009e5875cfb1ac567f8a8f6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6b90e9b7b847bb24a9cc8394f10c5be77d10521be3544515d2af3ff5f8c67d9a/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d6da8b7be1c593baffb442523f3ffd6fb96a9a2036d8bdac5996a5897c6efd90/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d6da8b7be1c593baffb442523f3ffd6fb96a9a2036d8bdac5996a5897c6efd90/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d6da8b7be1c593baffb442523f3ffd6fb96a9a2036d8bdac5996a5897c6efd90/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/Users/krystiank/db/maria_cnf",
                "Destination": "/etc/mysql/conf.d",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "d51df909be41a03544fba8ead271e3c26b69bacdb62e16bdd42b201018c43ba6",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/d51df909be41a03544fba8ead271e3c26b69bacdb62e16bdd42b201018c43ba6/_data",
                "Destination": "/var/lib/mysql",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "0a841717401c",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "3306/tcp": {},
                "5432/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password",
                "MYSQL_DATABASE=rssmonster",
                "ACCEPT_EULA=Y",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.12",
                "GPG_KEYS=177F4010FE56CA3336300305F1656F24C74CD1D8",
                "MARIADB_MAJOR=10.1",
                "MARIADB_VERSION=1:10.1.48+maria-1~bionic"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "mysqld"
            ],
            "Image": "mariadb:10.1",
            "Volumes": {
                "/etc/mysql/conf.d": {},
                "/var/lib/mysql": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "3980c17ef35aa15944f74bb088a21955c6e2d26fe859dc69fa2deb133f6d6579",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "pccr",
                "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "docker-compose.yml,docker-compose.local.yml",
                "com.docker.compose.project.environment_file": ".env",
                "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "/Users/krystiank/repos/pccr/pccr",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "local_maria_db",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.27.4"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "a1af979cc81d1f1f41ea8293f9f4d6adfdaca8a597b6e3d95bc02204f5b70edc",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "3306/tcp": null,
                "5432/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "6603"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/a1af979cc81d",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "pccr_vpc1": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "local_maria_db",
                        "0a841717401c"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "2eab3acc35ed4d269cf0f90a6f90f747b5e75f761af52c34bb4fe09e157e7542",
                    "EndpointID": "16e194805019936efa4a7df95357da0de558fd1825327ff782e979656031b113",
                    "Gateway": "10.1.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "10.1.0.4",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 24,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:01:00:04",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: Give an inspect in your container. docker container inspect <id_your_container>

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: Are you trying connect to your mariaDB from outside your docker?

Comment: So, you can do like this: mysql --user=root --password=password --port=6603 --host=10.1.0.1 testdb

Comment: im getting `Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.1.0.1' (60)`

Comment: can you show this ss -lptn | grep "0.0.0.0" also try replacing localhosby by 0.0.0.0. to confirm docker is listening on localhost.

Comment: ss -lptn | grep "0.0.0.0": 
`LISTEN   0         128              127.0.0.11:37761            0.0.0.0:*`

When i replace local host by 0.0.0.0
`Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0`

Comment: Mariadb's port is `3306`. Did you change that?

Comment: I've just done one test here in my machine. Firstly, you entry as root in mariaDB, so you must do this: In this case, I'm using MySQL. 1. select user, host from mysql.user; 2. Look at the host of your user 3. Change it for localhost 4. mysql -u <your_user> -h localhost -P <port> -p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out that mariadb does not care what ports i'm providing in docker compose, or maybe I have incorrect understanding of how this works - anyway mariadb is working on port 3306 inside docker container and I can access it with no problems from other container that is in the same network (vpc1) with:

```
    database: "testdb",
    dialect: "mariadb",
    username: "root",
    password: "password",
    host: "local_maria_db",
    port: 3306
```

To make it accessible from outside of the container and network, I had to change my docker compose ports from

```
ports:
  - "6603:5432"
```

to

```
ports:
  - "6603:3306"
```

So that when I call localhost on port 6603, it gets to actual port (3306) that mariadb is working on.

Case closed, I'm just not sure why is it always working on port 3306, the only way to change this port that I can see right now - add config (by volumes) that will be loaded as the last one and will override port config that mariadb has.

Adding this as an answer, maybe it will help someone in the future.

Comment: For me there was a case of also adding --prococol=TCP when connecting to localhost:
`mysql -u root -P 3306 --protocol=TCP -pTestPassword`. Leaving comment so it might help somebody, because googling problem brought me here.

Answer (score 1):

mysql/mariadb default port is 3306. Changing the mapping port of the container side in a docker-compose file does not mean that the mysql/mariadb service port is changed. Actually, it maps a host port to the service port inside of the container.

To change mysql/mariadb port one can change `port = 3306` in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` for example.

Answer (score 0):

in your docker compose i see you are using vpc1, if this is AWS, check your security groups, and allow from which computeror VM, you are connecting to the container from, to be able to access this.